# Cypress custom commands are not working with badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-custom-commands

When using badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor for Cypress BDD. I am not able to use the custom commands placed inside cypress support folder.

Following is the error I am getting on console

[WARNING] Ignoring this import because "cypress/support/commands.ts" was marked as having no side effects [ignored-bare-import]

```
cypress/support/e2e.ts:20:7:
  20 │ import './commands'
     ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

"sideEffects" is false in the enclosing "package.json" file

```
package.json:5:2:
  5 │   "sideEffects": false,
```

Tried changing the package.json:5:2:
5 │   "sideEffects": false,

to True, It worked but it will increase the bundle size and hence cannot go by this approach.

Looking for proper solution for this issue keeping sideeffects as false in package.json file